# The Master Spam List: Known spammers, spam domains, and associated IP addresses

Tags: discussion, spam, blacklist

This is a list of known spammers, spam domains, and IP addresses to which these domains point.

This list is derived from spam patterns observed on Super User as well as information from DNS and reverse DNS lookups from sources such as VirusTotal. It will be expanded as research progresses and as more spam is identified.

All IP address links go to the associated VirusTotal information page. Any subdomains of the listed domains are considered to be included.

Comment: Are these IP addresses purported to be the IPs of the servers which the spam points to, or the IPs of the servers from which the spammers are visiting?

Comment: These are the IPs to which the domains point.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What is the intended usage of the list as you envision it? Are you expecting others to add to it, and if so, should it be community-wiki?

Comment: My goal is a collaboratively edited list of known spam links which can be used as a reference for spam detection and flagging. CW is probably a good idea here.

Comment: The IPs are blocked automatically and blacklisted. The blatant ones get flag-killed within couple of hours at max. I don't understand the point of this post?

Comment: Some spam is sneakier than you think. The key issue this intends to address is the fact that spammers keep using different domains which are missed by the system and users as a whole.

Comment: I don't think this is the best place to post spam lists.

Comment: @oldmud0: why? Perhaps [meta.se] would be more appropriate? This list is based on the spam patterns we see on [su], so it would be natural to post it here on the local Meta.

Comment: Woodface started a "blacklist candidate" on meta some time ago, maybe you'd like to take some of the candidates for the The Master Spam List:
http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=blacklist%20candidate&page=2&pagesize=50&sort=relevance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Tenorshare and affiliates

*Data recovery, password recovery, video conversion, and PDF conversion spam. Has various other names such as SmartKey. The scale of the spam and the fact that multiple malware programs have been found on these IP addresses suggest that the conduct originates from a criminal organization.*

**IP addresses:**

- [54.201.153.20](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/54.201.153.20/information/)
- [184.168.229.155](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/184.168.229.155/information/)
- [54.69.177.37](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/54.69.177.37/information/)
- [67.20.74.163](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/67.20.74.163/information/)
- [50.87.141.154](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/50.87.141.154/information/)

**Domains:**

- tenorshare.com
- advancedpdfconverter.com
- androiddatarecoverypro.com
- any-data-recovery.com
- card-data-recovery.com
- excel-password-recovery.net
- fix-computer.net
- lost-password.net
- lostwindowspassword.com
- macvideoconverterpro.com
- password-master.net
- photorecovery-formac.com
- powerpointpasswordrecovery.net
- rarpasswordunlocker.net
- recover-windows-password.net
- recoverlostpassword.com
- sqlpassword-recovery.com
- windows7-password-reset.net
- windowspasswordcracker.com
- windowspasswordrecovery.net
- windowspasswordreset.net
- windowspasswordsrecovery.com
- wordpassword-recovery.com
- youtubedownloaderconverter.net

## Smart PC Fixer/Wise Recovery

*Fake system maintenance and tuning software; known adware and scam. Also associated with data recovery spam.*

**IP addresses:**

- [173.192.57.82](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/173.192.57.82/information/)

**Domains:**

- smartpcfixer.com
- 1fix.org
- cardrecoverypro.com
- drivertuner.com
- easyfix.org
- errorsfixer.org
- faq800.com
- fix1.org
- guru4pc.net
- howto4pc.org
- official-drivers.com
- pceasynow.com
- photorecoverypro.net
- regeasypro.com
- registryware.org
- smartfixer.net
- smartfixer.org
- wisefixer.com
- wisefixer.net
- wiserecovery.com

## Password Unlocker

*Password recovery spam; also associated with PDF conversion (**Nemo PDF**) and data recovery (**Hodo**).*

**IP addresses:**

- [162.144.77.13](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/162.144.77.13/information/)
- [69.164.205.180](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/69.164.205.180/information/)
- [162.144.79.192](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/162.144.79.192/information/)
- [108.178.27.101](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/108.178.27.101/information/)

**Domains:**

- passwordunlocker.com
- password-unlocker.com
- passwordtech.com
- goshareware.com
- nemopdf.com

## Apowersoft

*Screenshot and video downloader spam.*

**IP addresses:**

- [67.222.52.38](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/67.222.52.38/information/)
- [67.20.89.96](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/67.20.89.96/information/)
- [74.86.5.247](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/74.86.5.247/information/)
- [192.163.229.63](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/192.163.229.63/information/)

**Domains:**

- apowersoft.com
- downloadavideo.net
- downloaddailymotion.com
- free-download-youtube.com
- free-music-downloader.com
- screenshot.net
- video-download-capture.com
- videograbber.net

## Wasel

*VPN client spam. Uses seemingly legitimate blog links to deceive reviewers. Whois information indicates the operator is **Michael Maher** of **iSpire**.*

**IP addresses:**

- [95.211.216.155](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/95.211.216.155/information/)
- [37.48.74.7](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/37.48.74.7/information/)
- [109.236.83.24](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/109.236.83.24/information/)
- [173.199.114.19](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/173.199.114.19/information/)
- [216.155.134.164](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/216.155.134.164/information/)
- [93.190.137.136](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/93.190.137.136/information/)
- [67.55.100.153](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/67.55.100.153/information/)
- [216.155.134.169](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/216.155.134.169/information/)

**Domains:**

- wasel.com
- i-spire.com (*developer website*)
- internetwasel.com
- waselpro.com
- iwasl.com
- vpnfaqs.com
- vpnanswers.com
- bestcheapvpnservice.com
- unblockingtwitter.com
- openingblockedsite.com
- arabicdownloads.com
- arabicsoftdownload.com

---

## Repair Toolbox

*Office document data recovery recovery spam. Uses a seemingly valid question to disguise activity, then posts an answer using a different account promoting the product. An example question follows:*

> ### How to repair Corrupt MS Excel file?
>
> How to repair and recover corrupt MS excel file? I am unable to open corrupt MS Excel file due to virus infected, I have crucial Workbook sheet got lost, so how to get back corrupted MS Excel file. Please help me.

**IP addresses:**

- [192.185.37.236](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/192.185.37.236/information/)

**Domains**

*This list is non-exhaustive due to the extremely large number of domains associated with the above IP address.*

- *.repairtoolbox.com
- *.fixtoolbox.com
- [*document file extension*].repair
- [*document type*]repairtoolbox.com (any domain which ends with this string)
- all-recovery-inc.com

---

## Miscellaneous spammers

*These domains and products are known to be spam but no further association with the above have presently been identified.*

- Long Path Tool

  - Usually does not post a link; just mentions the program by name.
- Windows Password Breaker / Advanced Password Breaker

  - recoverwindowspassword.com
- Windows Password Buster

  - password-buster.com
- Remo Recover

  - remorecover.com
  - remosoftware.com
  - *Note:* Spam for this product often does not contain any links, which can make it harder to identify as such.
- Brorsoft
- Pavtube

  - Appears to be related to Brorsoft (see [1](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/173.193.175.141/information/), [2](https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/184.172.39.195/information/); further investigation needed)
  - Includes DVDAid, BDMagic, and Handbraker (notice that the latter has an intentionally confusing name)
- Preply (language learning spam)

  - preply.com
- Open File Tool (solutions for the recovery of corrupted files for many different file types)

  - openfiletool.com (208.76.175.50)
- Krojamsoft

  - Usually does not post a link; just mentions the program (Batch Rename) by name.

---

## Blog Spammers

Spam has links to blogs containing affiliate links to paid products.

- removeunwantedprograms.wordpress.com

  - Contains affiliate links to revouninstallerpro.com and mackeeperapp.mackeeper.com

Comment: A keyword search for "Remo Recover" at SU turned up [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/490012/i-just-installed-a-fresh-windows-and-formatted-drive-c-how-can-i-gt-the-files-b/490013#490013) which asks: *Do file recovery systems like Remo Recover work?*

Comment: It is, to an extent, a legitimate product, but I've seen it spammed at least twice here on Super User.

Comment: No time for a thorough edit, but let me add: *DBF repair, Krojamsoft, AquaSnap, XpressDox, BrorSoft, eScan, BackupChain, Debookee, Bionix*. Then there's the hall of fame: *Paragon* and *Acronis* (the latter being particularly nasty… as if they needed advertising).

Comment: @slhck Are you saying that Acronis is malware? I'm asking because I've used their [free WD backup application](http://support.wdc.com/product/downloaddetail.asp?swid=119) and I've never heard there's a problem with it. (Or did I misunderstand your comment?)

Comment: @ispiro No, it's not malware. They were just setting up lots of fake accounts to spam us.

Comment: @slhck Oh. OK. Thanks for the super-speedy response!

Comment: @slhck Ugh, Brorsoft. I have that one on my list: [FFmpeg GPL license violators who try to spam the mailing lists and forum](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3988). Some of these same clowns have spammed here at SU too, but I can't recall which. I flagged them and they go away.

Comment: @slhck: Is it certain that the spam came from Acronis, and not one of their resellers, or possibly someone wanting to ruin their reputation?

Comment: @BenVoigt The latter is rather implausible. I don't know about the former, as there is no easy way to tell.

Comment: As if anyone needs to ruin Acronis' reputation.

Comment: Another one for your list: inetfusion is getting a lot of "recommendations".

Comment: Another one is spam (which doesn't seem to contain any links - stupid spammers) for "long path tool". Example [Source path too long - BUT IT NEVER USED TO BE](http://superuser.com/a/931108) and http://superuser.com/a/930344/337631 (already deleted)

Comment: You may want to add msoutlooktools.com and friends.

Comment: Another regular spammer here: vanskeys.com

Comment: You can add openfiletool.com 208.76.175.50 (spam is answer [Could not complete your request because there is not enough memory. HELP!](http://superuser.com/a/980803))

Comment: @DavidPostill: Bear in mind that this answer is community wiki, so feel free to edit it as needed. Just try to be consistent with the formatting.

Comment: Also more details regarding Ispire / Ispirer on MSO here: [Info: Contacted by spammers (Ispirer Systems) referencing Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274892) I'd add a link to the post but I don't have enough rep to edit CW here.