# Why was this question about File manager deleted?

Tags: discussion

I've replied to a topic and some minutes later I saw that the [question was deleted as spam](https://superuser.com/questions/1179086).

Why was this done? Closing as offtopic "asking for product recommendations" is understandable, but not as spam.

Answer (score 4):

Since there's no spam in the question itself, I'll reproduce it here for <10K users:

> #### Any file manager supporting long file paths?
>
> Is there any file manager tool (like explorer) that support "long
>   paths" (filename + path longer than 260 chars) for win10?
>
> Win10 v1607 you could set LongPathEnabled so it should be possible but
>   only if the application support it (ntfs supports 32000+ but the win
>   API have had the 260 limit, but not any longer), as I have understood
>   it, and explorer dont.
>
> I know about command line tools like robocopy that can handle long
>   path but wanted one ordinary file manager with GUI.

I wasn't one of the flaggers, but my best guess is that it was identified as a spam seed, specifically for the Long Path Tool - a [known spammed product](https://meta.superuser.com/a/9250/380318). It's possible that the question was made to pave the way for answers advertising the LPT. And indeed, that tool does seem to fit the bill (a vaguely Explorer-like file manager with a GUI).

Comment: This is the reason

Comment: where do you see "Long Path Tool"? LongPathEnabled is something different

Comment: @magicandre1981 Right; it's the request for a long-path-handling tool that's possibly setting the stage for spam answers advertising the Long Path Tool. (That tool gets spammed quite a bit.)

Comment: ok, now I understand this, but it is still confusing. The SPAM detection should be less aggressive

Comment: @magicandre1981 It wasn't an automatic decision, a human made the judgement call, this was a possible setup for spam.

Answer (score 3):

Not the mod that deleted it but:

- It was *blatantly* off-topic and should have been closed rather than answered
- At a glance it reads a lot like LongPathTool spam, or a spam-seed for it.

It reads far too aggressively as "I must have this tool!" and from experience it *feels* like a spam seed.  At best the question deserved closure and, given a bit of time, to be [cleaned up](https://superuser.com/help/roomba).

Either way though I'm disinclined to undelete the question as it would still be close worthy, and I don't see any way it could be made on-topic. All they want is the software, not the help.

Comment: I understand that it would be closed as offtopic, but I don't understand the SPAM. undelete it and close it as  as offtopic "asking for product recommendations" and tell to him on ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if the user comes back he has no idea what he did wrong